# Set the order for output by flag.PrintDefaults()

Tags: go

I want to make the help message by my program more clear by changing stdout output. Now I using of **flag.Usage** for provide of additional information but also I want to change of an order of output the flags. Now flags are sorted by alphabetical but I need to change an order to logical. E.g.
Now:

```
./mytool --help
-aaa
  input file of aaa
-bbb 
  input file of bbb
-mode 
  job's mode
```

I wish :)

```
./mytool --help
-mode 
  job's mode
-aaa
  input file of aaa
-bbb 
  input file of bbb
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Undoable. Order is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [source code of flag](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/flag/flag.go#L385), it is impossible to modify the order of `flag.PrintDefault()`.

However, you can write a custom `flag.Usage` function, like the following example:

```
package main
import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    flag.String("aaa", "foo", "input file of aaa")
    flag.String("bbb", "foo", "input file of aaa")
    flag.String("mode", "foo", "job's mode")

    flag.Usage = func() {
        flagSet := flag.CommandLine
        fmt.Printf("Custom Usage of %s:\n", "./mytool")
        order := []string{"mode", "aaa", "bbb"}
        for _, name := range order {
            flag := flagSet.Lookup(name)
            fmt.Printf("-%s\n", flag.Name)
            fmt.Printf("  %s\n", flag.Usage)
        }
    }
    flag.Parse()
}
```

The output:

```
Custom Usage of ./mytool:
-mode
  job's mode
-aaa
  input file of aaa
-bbb
  input file of aaa
```